# Solution of system of two linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am considering here a very very elementary problem, but I am trying to convince it myself in a geometric way, which I didn't find myself.

Consider two linear equations over real numbers:
$$
a_1x+a_2y+a_3z=b, \hskip10mm a_1'x+a_2'y+a_3'z=b'.
$$
These equations represent planes of dimension two in space $\mathbb{R}^3$. The intersection of these two represent a common solution to them.

If we change the first equation by addition of these two, and keep second equation as it is;$$
(a_1+a_1')x+(a_2+a_2')y+(a_3+a_3')z=b+b', \hskip10mm a_1'x+a_2'y+a_3'z=b'.
$$
then their common solution should be a common solution of the original two (and vice-versa).

But, can we explain it in pictorial/geometric way, why the common solution set will remain unchanged in such case?

---

Algebraically, it is just *a verification question*, and not difficult to **verify**; but I am looking for *a geometric reason* if possible.

I am not looking for geometric interpretation of what is meant by unchanging the solution set.

Comment: Try to wrap your head around this.  We can think of a line as a representation of all planes that intersect that line.... (or a point as all lines passing through that point).  The set of planes that pass through a given line form a vector space and the sum of any two objects in the space is an object in the space.